# Tracking users that are transferred to another site from ours?

Tags: tracking, cookie

Is it possible to track what a user does on another site after they are redirected there by your site?

We run a site that sells education courses. Some of our courses are held by 3rd party companies. When a person wants to take one of the courses that a 3rd party holds, we transfer them to the 3rd party's website.

We would like to know if they are perusing other education choices on the 3rd party's website, if possible.

We use GA to track the outbound link and track where the user actually goes, but once they are there, who knows???

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to know what users do _only_ on sites you are semi-affiliated with? If there is no connection between you and the site you want to track users on, tracking might be unethical (and possibly illegal).

Comment: A further clarification: how 3rd-partyish are the 3rd parties? Are they people you work with closely or are they completely separate entities, with which you have formal dealings? They may not _want_ you to be tracking their users. (Spoiler: they probably don't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short: yes its [possible](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en), but you will get limited information

another way: your 3rd party company share a GA view with you

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 GA codes on a webpage?

Comment: yes: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400

Comment: We will have to ask our affiliates to install the Universal tracking so that we can track our users.